Why is the console.log() method within quotations?
I'm still very new to JavaScript and I recently read through the documentation for setTimeout() and saw the following example:


setTimeout("console.log('Hello World!');", 500);



How does this work? Are we not making console.log() a string? I tried to find more information about this but I don't really know where to look or how to properly ask the question. Does this apply to all functions and methods? And if so, what determines if I need to use quotation marks or not?
I tried the above sample and it works, I just don't understand why it works since it seems like we make the whole thing into a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#code

The string is turned into a function automatically, but DO NOT USE THAT TECHNIQUE. Pass a function to setTimeout(), not a string.

According to MDN, one of the ways to use setTimeout is:
setTimeout(code, delay)

where code works as part of:

An alternative syntax that allows you to include a string instead of a function, which is compiled and executed when the timer expires. This syntax is not recommended for the same reasons that make using eval() a security risk.

Executing a string as code is not recommended; prefer passing an anonymous function instead.
This would be better and achieve the same effect:
setTimeout(() => console.log('Hello World!'), 500);

